# Set second axis in proportion of first axis

Tags: javascript, highcharts, axis

I have a chart which contains two series, and each of them has its own `yAxis`. I need to automatically set the second axis maximum to 13.5% of the first axis maximum. For example, if the first axis goes from 0 to 100, then I want the second axis to go from 0 to 13.5 (No matter the second series value).

The only way I found to achieve this is to calculate the max of the first series, and then affect it to the max of the second axis. But this is not what I really want. [See this JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/6eq4hy9b/2/)

My fiddle seems to work, but in reality, I am not calculating the second axis maximum in a good way, as I refer to the first *series* maximum and not the first *axis* maximum.

Does anyone knows a general way to set the max of an axis accordingly to the max of another axis ?

The `linkedTo` attribute from Highcharts axis is close to what I want, but I need to add a coefficient. I don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no default API function in Highcharts that would allow that.

If you want to get percentage of max of created axis, then you can get it in load event of chart (API: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.events.load )or in callback (as in demo below). Next you will need to update second axis' max.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/cg0c5tkd/

```
function(chart){
        chart.yAxis[1].update({max: chart.yAxis[0].getExtremes().max * 0.135});
    }
```

Comment: The callback is an extremely good idea ! I did not know `Highcharts.Chart()` had a second parameter. Thanks, works like a charm.

Comment: I have just realized that it does not work when I drilldown: the second axis stays fixed with the values from before drilldown. Any idea on how I can modify this axis after the drilldown? I only found the drilldown event, which is before the chart is actually drilldowned. (Sorry if I'm not clear)

Comment: @Kabulan0lak Could you post live example, like jsFiddle? You could call this function in setTimeout. Zero milliseconds of delay seems to be an enough amount of time. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/zd5do0s7/

Comment: I've created a new post for this problem, but you solved it all again :) Thanks ! I was surprised that when I log the chart in the console, I have `yAxis[0].max = 25000` but when I log directly the `chart.yAxis[0].max` it prints 80000. The `setTimeout()` function solves this issue. Thank you very much again. The new post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32068994/set-axis-extremes-dynamically-on-drilldown?noredirect=1#comment52045382_32068994

Comment: Can you write an answer on it so I can validate the solution ?