# Set axis extremes dynamically on drilldown

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am working on a chart with two axes, which are proportional, i.e., the second axis maximum is exactly 13.5% of the first axis maximum.

I managed to do this with the callback functionnality of Highcharts, as @KacperMadej suggested me in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31945262/set-second-axis-in-proportion-of-first-axis):

```
function (chart) {
        chart.yAxis[1].update({
            max: chart.yAxis[0].getExtremes().max * 0.135
        });
 }
```

It works great, but when I drilldown on my chart, the second axis stays fixed to its values before drilldown. I can't find a way to affect this axis after the drilldown has been loaded.

Any idea on how I can get an *after drilldown* event on Highcharts ?

Here is what I have attempted so far:

```
chart: {
        alignTicks: false,
        events: {
            drilldown: function () {
                this.yAxis[1].update({
                    max: this.yAxis[0].getExtremes().max * 0.135
                });
            }
        }
}
```

This does not work at all as the second axis stays exactly the same before and after drilldown. See my [JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/cg0c5tkd/4/) (Click on '2015' to drilldown).

Comment: You can catch [drillUp](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.events.drillup) / [drillDown](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.events.drilldown) events and call your actions

Comment: @SebastianBochan It is what I am trying to do with `chart.events.drilldown` but `this` keyword seems to refer to the chart before the drilldown is done

Comment: Fixed demo: http://jsfiddle.net/zs4vs08t/3/

Comment: @SebastianBochan This demo does not fit my needs. I need to calculate the max of yAxis[0] (which auto scales) after the drilldown, and affect it to the yAxis[1]. Am I not clear ? In my fiddle, you see the first axis autoscaling, and the second does not move as it should do (it should autoscale to 0.135 of the first axis max)

Comment: @SebastianBochan I tried using the event argument of the drilldown function: `e.target.yAxis[0].max` but it gives me the `oldMax` value instead of the `max` value. Do you know why ?

Comment: @SebastianBochan Kacper Madej solved the issue by using the function `setTimeout()`. That's perfect. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could call this function:

```
function(chart){
    chart.yAxis[1].update({max: chart.yAxis[0].getExtremes().max * 0.135});
}
```

in setTimeout in drilldown event. Zero milliseconds of delay seems to be an enough amount of time. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/zd5do0s7

(connected question: [Set second axis in proportion of first axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31945262/set-second-axis-in-proportion-of-first-axis))